# Spring JPA Join

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am a Beginner to spring framework,

I am facing some issue on Repository and SQL connection part.
I want to fetch details from two tables using join query.

Please find below the error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'commentController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'joinRepository'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'joinRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class com.example.jpa.model.JoinQuery   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   com.example.jpa.JpaOneToManyDemoApplication.main(JpaOneToManyDemoApplication.java:14)
>   [classes/:na]

```
select c.created_at , c.updated_at , p.content,c.text , p.id , c.posting_dummy 
from     post p join  comment c 
on  p.id = c.posting_dummy;
```

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface JoinRepository  extends JpaRepository<JoinQuery, Long>
{
@Query(value = " select  c.created_at , c.updated_at , p.content,c.text , p.id , c.posting_dummy "
            + "  from   post p join  comment c   on  p.id = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
public  List<JoinQuery> queryBy(Long id);
}
```

POJO:

```
public class JoinQuery 
{
private Long id;
private Date createdAt;
private Date updatedAt;
private String content;
private String text;
private  Post posting_dummy;

// Getter and Setter for fields       
}
```

Controller :

```
@RestController
public class CommentController {

@Autowired
private CommentRepository commentRepository;

@Autowired
private PostRepository postRepository;

@Autowired
private JoinRepository joinRepository;

@GetMapping("/posts/{postId}/comments")
public List<JoinQuery>  getAllCommentsByPostId(@PathVariable (value = "postId") Long postId
                                                    ) 
{
System.out.println("hi am here ");
return joinRepository.queryBy(postId);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`public class JoinQuery` need the `@Entity` annotation.

```
@Entity
public class JoinQuery 
{
private Long id;
private Date createdAt;
private Date updatedAt;
private String content;
private String text;
private  Post posting_dummy;

// Getter and Setter for fields       
}
```

Also the query sould not be a native query use:

```
@Query(value = " select  new <package of jpaquery>.JoinQuery(c.created_at , c.updated_at , p.content,c.text , p.id , c.posting_dummy) "
            + "  from   post p.c")
```

BTW: Do not use an Entity as a return value of a controler. Learn about 3tier architecture

Comment: Hi Jens actually  i have two diffrent entity  one is   post another one is  comment ....  Through this two entity  i want to achieve  join query  (that is why i put  POJO class (JoinQuery))

Comment: Hi all , Pls share  input  on this .....  Waiting for your reply